# How to stream a regular html-js website via RTSP?

Tags: javascript, html, amazon-ec2, rtsp, rtsp-server

I'm trying to find a way of streaming a website via RTSP.

Note: **I do not want to embed an RTSP stream in my website! I want the opposite**

I have an AWS EC2 server, which can be used as the RTSP server, and I have a regular website containing HTML+JS+CSS that I want to "open" on my server (via some browser or a script), and stream the feed from that website via RTSP.

Is it possible?

I tried to find a solution for a while (even with the help of GPT) and couldn't find any good one yet...